# How to access the value of a function generated column in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL

select count(*) col, column1, column2, column3 from TempTable 
group by column1, column2, column3
order by 1 desc

so the column generated by the count will return a number and there are 17 rows that do not have the number 1 (duplicate rows as columns 1, 2 and 3 are primary keys) and i want to delete any that have the count greater than 1?

Comment: how will you prevent deleting all records? You will need to delete only extra records, and keep one intact (and which one?), this will be hard, this is why you should have defined integrity contsraints on your table. Trying to cleanup bad integrity is not always simple.

Comment: For the moment deleting faulty records is all i need, just looking for a quick fix, not a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the having-clause:

```
select count(*) col, column1, column2, column3
from TempTable group by column1, column2, column3
having count(*) > 1
order by 1 desc
```

To delete:

```
delete tt
from TempTable tt
     inner join (select count(*) col, column1, column2, column3
                 from TempTable group by column1, column2, column3
                 having count(*) > 1) tmp
     on tmp.column1 = tt.column1
     and tmp.column2 = tt.column2
     and tmp.column3 = tt.column3
```

Comment: How can i apply this for a delete, to remove all the records that have a count greater then 1?

Comment: @Grace: I have edited my answer with an example. Basically you can delete using a join.

Answer (score 1):

First you insert the data in temporary table:

```
select count(*) col, column1, column2, column3
into #temp
from TempTable group by column1, column2, column3 order by 1 desc
```

Then, you delete the data, and insert it from the #temp table:

```
delete from TempTable 
go

insert into TempTable select column1, column2, column3 from #temp
go
```